# Azure Api gateway for web apps instead of apis

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

Is it possible to have an kind of api gateway to redirect requests for different web apps?

Foe example:

Domain: abc.com

Abc.com/ -> abc-com-home.azurewebsites.net
Abc.com/map -> abc-com-map.azurewebsites.net

And every request in teh apps should use rhe same pattern.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have an kind of api gateway to redirect requests for different web apps?

Per my understanding, you could leverage the [Set backend service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService) policy to redirect an incoming request to the related back-end. Also, you could leverage the path-based rule for the application gateway with your azure web apps to distribute your request(s) to the relevant azure web app. Details, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal).

> Abc.com/ -> abc-com-home.azurewebsites.net Abc.com/map -> abc-com-map.azurewebsites.net

Per my understanding, I would map a custom domain (`Abc.com`) for `abc-com-home.azurewebsites.net`, then I would leverage the [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for my `abc-com-home.azurewebsites.net` to redirect the request(s) to the related azure web apps based on the request path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the application gateway can do it, but you must do it via powershell.  If you need SSL, the you must configure for end to end ssl since webapps cant be a a virtual network.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-powershell